# Searching and Filtering Node.js array using C++

Tags: c++, node.js

I have a node.js app with some arrays of 100K objects. Im doing .filter and .find and .include operations on the arrays but its taking a very long time to complete the operations, which is expected. Operations example is, I have two arrays with 100K items, i want to find the items that are in one array and not the other array, and then find the items where the id property is present in both arrays but other properties have changed. Im trying to think of ways to speed up the operations. Is it possible to pass these off to a C++ library within node? And if so, are there any libraries available to do so?  Otherwise, anyone have any suggestions of speeding up performance on massive array operations in node?

Comment: Just changed my code to use Maps instead of arrays and performance is orders of magnitude better. Still takes a couple minutes but very acceptable.